# encrypt wifi on Android?

Tags: wi-fi

CM Security app on my galaxy 5 has an alert telling me my phone is RISKY, the wifi is not encrypted. How do I encrypt the wifi on my phone? I haven't tried anything because I do not know what to do.

Comment: Is this your phone connecting to a WiFi source, or you using your phone as a WiFi hotspot?

Comment: It's my home wifi and I'm sick to my stomach now. I must research how to encrypt my router. Thank you so much.

Comment: What CM Security app are you using that is telling you your phone is "RISKY"? Wifi itself is not encrypted. Your connections to things like websites (SSL) are encrypted. Now your router should have a password to prevent anyone from being able to access your network.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that the wifi network you are connected to is not encrypted, not your phone.  Most open hotspots are not encrypted, it's just warning you of that fact.  If you are on your home personal wifi, research how to enable WPA2 on your router.

Comment: It's my home personal wifi so I do need to research how to encrypt my home wifi. Thank you!!